# Building PL/Java for PostgreSQL 9.4.1 on OpenSuse 13.2

Tags: postgresql, makefile, pljava

I followed the build instructions on pljava github page, fixed all the required environment variables and attempted to build it. I got this error.

```
$ make 
 make[1]: Entering directory /host/clara/devel/pljava/build/classes/pljava
 make[1]: /host/clara/devel/pljava/src/java/pljava/Makefile: No such file or directory 
 make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/host/clara/devel/pljava/src/java/pljava/Makefile'.  Stop. 
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/host/clara/devel/pljava/build/classes/pljava' 
 make: *** [pljava_all] Error 2
```

This is a previously reported error on this project's wiki. The make file is broke and I couldn't find a solution anywhere. Has anyone else attempted to build this on opensuse for `pg 9.4.1`? Is there a way to circumvent this?

I am also new to postgres and it is not that I will be using pljava to write DB functions in java. I had sql jobs on my old mssql server which call some jars. Is `pljava` mandatory for this on pg?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest building it with maven. The installation manual for pljava needs an update. Remember to have all the prerequisites and environment variables configured before you attempt a build. This project also lacks a clear list of prerequisites for successful building. I attempted a build myself and fixed them all interpreting the error messages. The project's source code doesn't build on maven by itself. You have to fix the maven nar dependencies. There are multiple forks of this project on github which have them. You can try [this](https://github.com/TavoloPerUno/pljava/wiki/Building-pl-java). This also lists the prerequisites.